# calculation of Transitive Closure

Tags: algorithms, graphs

This question is not from homework, but rather as preparation for the test:

The calculation of place-in is a calculation in which the algorithm does not need space beyond the output size (beyond
beyond a fixed space complexity). Show how, given a graph (E, V = G), the transitive closure  can be calculated
in-place in the calculation of G * = (V, E *)

I tried to represent the graph using a adjacency matrix. what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Show that you can calculate the transitive closure by an algorithm that only modifies values in this matrix and perhaps some fixed number of variables declared in the code. (A fixed amount of storage "doesn't count".)

Which intermediate results would you compute?

Answer (score 0):

The transitive closure of a graph $G = (V,E)$ is $G^{+} = (V,E \cup E')$, where $E'$ is a (possibly empty) set of additional edges which represent the transitive paths. That is, the set of edges in $G^+$ is a superset of the set of edges in $G$.

Moreover, suppose you have a graph $G = (V,E)$, and find a new edge $e$ that isn't in $G$ but is in $G^+$. Then the new graph $G' = (V, E \cup \{ e \})$ has the useful property that $G^+ = G'^+$. That is

It's worth proving both of these results; it's not hard.

From this, it seems like you should be able to construct $G^+$ from $G$ by just adding edges. Once you have added an edge, you have effectively constructed a new graph $G'$ such that $G \subseteq G' \subseteq G^+$.

How would you find new edges to add? And when should such an algorithm terminate?